# If a linear function maps the orthonormal basis of one subspace to another, is the function orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to write the following in one of my homework problems. This feels like it ought to be true but I have this feeling like it might not be. If it is true, I don't know what else I need to say to justify it:

"Let $V$ and $W$ be two vector subspaces. By the Gram-Schmidt process, they both have orthonormal bases. Define a function $f$ that maps each orthonormal basis vector of $V$ to a unique orthonormal basis vector of $W$ and extend by linearity. Then $f$ is orthogonal."

Could someone tell me or help me see why this is true or untrue?

Answer (score 1):

If $\dim V = \dim W$, you are correct. Note that an orthogonal transformation $f$ is linear and preserves the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ in the sense that for $u, v \in V$,
$$
\langle u,v\rangle = \langle fu, fv\rangle.
$$
Let $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ be an orthonormal basis of $V$ produced by the Gram-Schmidt procedure and let $e_1',\ldots,e_n'$ be an orthonormal basis for $W$ produced by the Gram-Schmidt procedure. For $u, v \in V$, $u = \sum u_ie_i$ and $v = \sum v_ie_i$. Then,
$$
\langle u, v\rangle = \langle \sum u_ie_i, \sum v_ie_i\rangle = \sum u_iv_i.
$$
Generally, suppose $\sigma: \{1, \ldots , n\} \to \{1, \ldots, n\}$ is a bijection, suppose $fe_i = e_{\sigma(i)}'$ and extend $f$ linearly:
$$
\langle fu, fv\rangle = \langle f(\sum u_ie_i), f(\sum v_ie_i)\rangle=\langle \sum u_ife_i, \sum v_ife_i\rangle \\
=\langle \sum u_ie_{\sigma(i)}', \sum v_ie_{\sigma(i)}'\rangle = \sum u_iv_i.
$$
Hence, $f$ is an orthogonal transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On my screen it looks like you've written :At the same time,
[Math Processing Error]
⟨∑uifei,∑vifei⟩=⟨∑uiei′,∑viei′⟩=∑uivi.
 Hence, f is an orthogonal transformation. Did you mean to write this to get me to do the rest of the work myself? Or is my computer malfunctioning?

Comment: @user52969 does the problem persist? It looks fine on my screen. Try refreshing the page. Just note that it is a simple expansion of the inner product to show that $\langle u, v\rangle = \langle fu,fv\rangle$ if you still can't read my answer.